# getting data from database and adding character

Tags: jquery

this is the function that i am using and the php that i am using

```
  $(function() {
 var availableTags = [
   <?php

     $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","dbnpatient");
      if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
      echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
      }

      $query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT pname FROM tblnpatient");
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){

    echo $row['pname'];


}
        ?>
];
$( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
  source: availableTags
});
```

});

i need the data would be like this "John Cruz", "Jerry Tom", "Garry Tim". Data with double quote and coma

Comment: writing server side logic right in the middle of javascript output makes no sense. Create array and output using `json_encode` and leave your javascript readable

Answer (score 0):

You need to encode the result via `json_encode` function to get the desired result:

```
<?php
    $con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","dbnpatient");
    if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
        echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
    }
    $tags = array();
    $query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT pname FROM tblnpatient");
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
        $tags[] = $row['pname'];
    }
    $availableTags = json_encode($tags);
?>
<script>
$(function() {
    var availableTags = <?php echo $availableTags;?>;
    $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
      source: availableTags
    });
}); 
</script>
```